# Tampermonkey userscript to scroll to first image with alt tag

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, tampermonkey, userscripts

[image: Example of training site and the html makeup]

I use a training site, that has a lot of courses. It is rather annoying that it does not remember the scroll position of your last course. I am trying to write a tampermonkey userscript to scroll to the first image with an alt tag of "Not Started" but it does not seem to work.

Here is what I have tried so far

```
var myList = document.getElementsByTagName("img");

for(var i=0;i<myList.length;i++)
{
    if(myList[i].alt == "Not Started")
    {
        var pos = myList[i].offsetTop;
    }
}
window.scrollTo(0,pos);
```

Answer (score 1):

Two things here:

1. `var pos`

if you declare (mention for the first time) the variable `pos` in a for loop, it won't work. You have to declare it before where the rest of the function can read it.

2. `window.addEventListener('load', (event) => {`

i'm not sure why but at least in the snippet below this was needed. Perhaps the js starts running before the window loads and therefore cannot set `window.scrollTo`. If you have any questions leave it in the comments.

```js
window.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
  var myList = document.querySelectorAll('img');
  var pos;
  for (var i = 0; i < myList.length; i++) {
    if (myList[i].alt == "Not Started") {
      pos = myList[i].offsetTop;
      break;
    }
  }
  window.scrollTo(0, pos);
});
```

```html
<img src='https://placekitten.com/800/800'>
<img src='https://placekitten.com/800/800' alt='Not Started'>
<img src='https://placekitten.com/700/800' alt='Not Started'>
```

Comment: weird it doesnt seem to be working

`// ==UserScript==
// @name         New Userscript
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  try to take over the world!
// @author       You
// @grant        none
// @include      https://example.com/*
// ==/UserScript==


    window.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
  var myList = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
  var pos;
  for (var i = 0; i < myList.length; i++) {
    if (myList[i].alt == "Not Started") {
      pos = myList[i].offsetTop;
    }
  }
  window.scrollTo(0, pos);
});`

Comment: "@include      https://example.com/*": you need to set this to the website you want it to work on. I doubt it's 'example.com'. Let me know if this works. and remember to add `/*` at the end as you did here, that part is correct.

Comment: also I just changed the code by one line  (I added `break` at line 7) so you should update that as well.

Comment: i did change example.com, but SO doesnt allow the actual site

Comment: it's hard to say why it's not working. It clearly works here in this snippet. I guess check to make sure you have the extension enabled. it could also be that your site isn't using image tags but i'm not sure if that's a real possibility.

Comment: I just changed it to look for actual images instead of image tags using `document.querySelectorAll('img');`. Let me know if that works.

Comment: bazar. ive tried all types of ways and no luck. wish i could show what i see, but cant publicly share the page

Comment: it's possible that the website has some sort of protection on it. Can you try testing it on another website (using a different alt)? If it works I think you should mark this as correct and make a new question specifically about that website